# android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8 in multiple project

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I am trying to do 'cordova build android' in a multiply project. 
projects structure like :

```
android(MainApp)
|-- build.gradle
|-- setting.gradle
|-- gradle.properties
|--LibProject1
   |-- build.gradle
   |-- setting.gradle
   |-- gradle.properties
|--LibProject2
   |-- build.gradle
   |-- setting.gradle
   |-- gradle.properties
   |--LibProject2_1
      |-- build.gradle
      |-- setting.gradle
      |-- gradle.properties
```

'cordova prepare android' and 'cordova plugins' run successfully, but 'cordova build android' failed in very long and strange error:

```
Running command: ******\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
ANDROID_HOME=*****
JAVA_HOME=*****
Running: ******android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b ****platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes
precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:444)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '*****platforms\android\LibProject1\build.gradle' line: 49

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':LibProject1'.
> Project with path ':LibProject2' could not be found in project ':LibProject1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.142 secs

******platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "******\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b 
******\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
Error: ******platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
      at ChildProcess.whenDone (****AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
      at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

seems it said my LibProject1/build.gradle has some wrong but 'gradle build' successed and I got apk run normally.

finally I found that when 'cordova build android' ran, file LibProject1/build.gradle is being changed auto. for example:

```
dependencies{
 compile project(':LibProject1')
}
```

is changed to

```
dependencies{
 debugCompile project(path: ":LibProject1", configuration: "debug")
 releaseCompile project(path: ":LibProject1", configuration: "release")
}
```

I am realy confuse with this problem. 
Does anyone can help me? and Thank you for reading so long

Comment: Sometimes the versions of Gradle and Android Tools do not mach, so download latest Gradle (http://gradle.org/getting-started-gradle-java/) and run Android SDK Manager and update the packages. Version number in file build.gradle must match version number of Android SDK Build-tools. Be sure to have GRADLE_HOME set (I dont see it in your log) and update the PATH variable.

Comment: Hi, thank u for reply. I updated Android SDK Buil-tools to 23.0.0, and I am using latest gradle v2.4. And actually I have set GRADLE_HOME in system but I dont know why it not show in running message. And I am using jdk 1.7. after these update I ran 'cordova build' again but still got same error and build.gradle is still changed strangely

Comment: Ok, so this is not the reason ;). Did you search the whole directory content  for the String "LibProject2"? In one configuration there must be this mismatch.